# C++ and Objective-C Combination

Tags: c++, objective-c

I need to know whether I can write the whole class in C++ and use it in XCode using Objective-C?

I need to write a code to query HTML using POST method and I think the best approach is to use either C++ or C#.

Umair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, with C++ that is. From the chapter "[Using C++ With Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html)" in Apples "[The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)" document:

> Apple’s Objective-C compiler allows you to freely mix C++ and Objective-C code in the same source file. This Objective-C/C++ language hybrid is called Objective-C++. With it you can make use of existing C++ libraries from your Objective-C applications.

Basically all you have to do is use the file extension `.mm` and then you may mix Objctive-C and C++ freely (see the chapter linked to above for some exceptions).

Answer (score 2):

C++, yes.  C#, no.

Objective-C is an extension of C and can transparently interoperate with C++.

Unless you have some existing HTTP library that you want to recycle, I would suggest exploring the options built into the system first.  There are a bunch of stackoverflow questions on the subject.